# JS: conditionally adding adding in the middle of an array?

Tags: javascript

If i have an array of `data`,

```
const data = [
   {
     name: "dog",
     age: 11
   }, 
   {
     name: "cat",
     age: 21,
   }
]
```

I want to add an object in the middle of that if a condition is true:

```
const shouldAddNewAnimal = true;

const animal = {
   name: "tiger",
   age : 22,
}
```

How would I write that without an `else` ?

```
const data = [
   {
     name: "dog",
     age: 11
   }, 
   foo ? animal : {};
   {
     name: "cat",
     age: 21,
   }
]
```

above is the only way I can think of writing it but I dont want to insert an empty object in there if the condition is not true.

Answer (score 2):

You could spread with arrays, one with the wanted object and the other empty.

```js
const
    shouldAddNewAnimal = true,
    animal = { name: "tiger", age: 22 },
    data = [
        { name: "dog", age: 11 },
        ...(shouldAddNewAnimal ? [animal] : []),
        { name: "cat", age: 21 }
    ];

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spread operator:

```js
const foo = true;
const animal = { name: "mouse", age: 10 };

const data = [
   {
     name: "dog",
     age: 11
   }, 
   ...(foo ? [animal] : []),
   {
     name: "cat",
     age: 21,
   }
]

console.log(data);
```

This will result in the `animal` being extracted out of its enclosing array and added to the "outer" array.

In the case of "else" path, spreading the `null` will result in nothing being added to the "outer" array.

Comment: please try with `null`. and try to spread `false` ...

Comment: @NinaScholz it throws an error, strangely... I removed that example. Thank for pointing it out!

Comment: your solution still insert an item, even if `null` to the array.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this by adding null's and filtering them out like so using `filter`

```js
const shouldAddNewAnimal = false;
const animal = {
   name: 'parrot',
   age:12
}

let data = [
   {
     name: "dog",
     age: 11
   }, 
   shouldAddNewAnimal ? animal : null,
   {
     name: "cat",
     age: 21
   }
].filter(item => item !== null);

console.log(data);
```

```js
const shouldAddNewAnimal = true;
    const animal = {
       name: 'parrot',
       age:12
    }

    let data = [
       {
         name: "dog",
         age: 11
       }, 
       shouldAddNewAnimal ? animal : null,
       {
         name: "cat",
         age: 21
       }
    ].filter(item => item !== null);

    console.log(data);
```